# Creating and attaching a .txt file to email in Xcode

Tags: ios, email, text

I want to make an iOS app that makes/creates a text file (.txt) then sends it as an email.

The issue i am having is the data to be encrypted pops up with the error "use of undeclared identifier"

**[mailController addAttachmentData:dataToBeEncrypted mimeType:@"text/plain"**

***Here is my .m file***

```
//
//  FileIoViewController.m
//  FileIo
//
//  Created by Flare gun on 6/24/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Flaregunapplications. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FileIoViewController.h"

@interface FileIoViewController ()

@end

@implementation FileIoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) writeToTextFile{
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate =self;
        [mailController setSubject:@"Records"];
        [mailController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:YES];
        [mailController addAttachmentData:dataToBeEncrypted mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:@"Records.txt"];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
        [mailController release];
    } else {
        //Pop up a notification
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Could not send email. Verify Internet conneciton and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Are you declaring dataToBeEncrypted somewhere?

Comment: Dont know how to declare it. How would i declare it?

Answer (score 1):

To declare `dataToBeEncrypted` use something like:

```
NSData *dataToBeEncrypted = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```